# How does CUDA know when to Synchronize?

Tags: cuda

Assuming I have a set of float gpu pointers -> dataset: [A,B,C,D]

I am iterating it so that to compute B, I need A, for C I need B etc.

If I do

```
A = computeA()

for prevData, data in dataset:
    data = computeData(prevData)
```

Does CUDA automatically queue them so that one finishes after the other? Do I need to do deviceSynchronize()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: if they are called in the same stream (which, unless you are explicitly defining streams, they are), they will be executed one after the other.

The calls to kernels are asynchronous, but that does not mean they will happen at the same time, it only means that the CPU will not wait for the kernel to finish before queuing the next operation. You can add a `deviceSynchronize()` if you desire, as unless there is some heavy CPU computation between the calls, it will have no effect in the execution, it will just halt the CPU until the kernel is finished.

Comment: Okay, so if I have to completely seperate operations that are not related. Say A and B. and I run both kernels, they are actually running back to back? In such a situation I should have two streams for better paralleization?

Comment: @raaj if you are actually getting acceleration on GPUs, 99.9% sure that your kernels use 100% of the processors when run. Otherwise you are running too small of a computation and likely not gaining speed in GPU. Therefore, I do not think you need to separate them in streams. You may want to it for the logic of your code, but not because of speed. Streams are generally very useful mainly for overlapping memcpy and compute